# NSMutableOrderedSet implementation

Tags: objective-c, swift, complexity-theory, nsorderedset

I wondered, how `NSMutableOrderedSet` could be implemented because I wanted to know what time complexity inserting/looking for/accessing an element by index has since it is not specified in the docs. I thought it could be a self-balancing binary tree on top of a list. However, I don't think a list is very efficient for looking up an element by index (`O(n)`). An array would however be extremely unsuitable for inserting values (`O(n)`). It would be great if someone could give me a hint.

Comment: You need to create your set from an array. If you create a NSOrderedSet you won't be able to modify/add any object to it later. If you would like to modify your ordered set you need to use NSMutableOrderedSet

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I'll change the question a little - using a NSOrderedSet a binary tree operating on top of an array would be the obvious solution, wouldn't it?

Comment: Please note that implementation may change over time, or even at runtime. See this example for NSArray: http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html

Comment: Just treat your array as a regular array and get your array orderedSet value from it if needed. I have an extension for that if you would like to

Comment: @LeoDabus I don't know what you mean. Sometimes you can't avoid using `NSOrderedSet` for example when using Core Data ;)

Comment: @OliverBorchert I am not familiarised with Core Data so I can't say anything about it but I understand your point